# How to change the value of a perticular field (state) of different documents having same uid(one of the field like state) under a collection?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am making an eCommerce app in which when **Add to cart** button is pressed in **ProductDetails** activity, the details of that respective product is added under the **"Pending"** collection with the **product id** as the document name with the fields as shown in the photo. Now there will be multiple users adding the products but they are filtered with the help of **whereEqualsTo("uid", user.getUid())**. So my question is when I place the order in placeOrder activity, I want to change the value of the **state** field form cart to order for that particular uid. How to do that???

```
placeOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            db.collection("Pending")
                    .whereEqualTo("uid", user.getUid())
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    Map<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
                    cartMap.put("state", "orders");
                    db.collection("Pending").document().update(cartMap)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                          finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Please edit the question to explain what isn't working the way you expect.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: No sir @AlexMamo

Comment: If I'll write you an answer, are willing to try it and accept if it works?

Comment: yes sure@AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first is the call of the `.document()` method without passing any argument, which actually creates a new id. The second problem is that you are not looping to get the result. So to solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
placeOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        db.collection("Pending")
                .whereEqualTo("uid", user.getUid())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                db.collection("Pending").document(document.getId()).update("state", "orders")
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                //finish();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
});
```

Be also aware that calling `finish();` will finish the activity when the first update completes, that's the reason why I commented that line.

Comment: Did it@Alex Mamo